# Collection of sets that are supersets of a collection of required sets, that is optimal under a cost function

Tags: optimization, algorithms, nonlinear-optimization, discrete-optimization

I have a set of elements, $U$.

I have a collection of subsets of $U$, which I call my requirements, $R$.

The problem: Find a $T$, a collection of subsets of $U$, such that $\forall r\in R, \exists t\in T \textrm{ s.t. } r\subseteq t$ that (locally) minimises $\sum_i |t_i|^2$.

I wondered if anyone knew if this falls within a formal class of problems for which I could use an off the shelf algorithm to solve. I don't know a lot about the area I'm afraid, so asking for help here. I checked out Integer linear programming and the set cover problem but I don't think either of these are appropriate. Equality constrained least squares was closer, but I couldn't formulate my problem in that way. It can be seen as combinatorial optimisation problem, but is there a good algorithm I could use?

**Additional practical consideration:**

The optimisation doesn't need to be that good for it to be useful to me.

If $N=|U|$ then I have N ~ 10000m where m might be between 2 and 200. $|R|=N$, and for each requirement, $r\in R$ there will be approximately of order $m$ other $r'$ which are similar to $r$.

Comment: What does $\sum_i |t_i|^2$ mean?  Is this cardinality or absolute value?  What is the index set for $i$?

Comment: $|t_i|$ is the cardinality. The sum is over all $t_i\in T$. Thanks.

Comment: Squaring the cardinality of the sets is a rather odd thing to do. If you just had $\sum_i |t_i|$, this would be easily solved: $T = \{\bigcup R\}$ would be minimal. But because of the squaring, if the overlap of two sets in $R$ is small enough, you are better off not taking their union.

Comment: Hi Paul, yes as you say it would be trivial if the function to minimise were linear in the cardinality of the sets. The reason for taking the square in this case is that I'm interested in solving a computational problem on the resulting $t_i$ which scales quadratically with $|t_i|$. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can formulate the problem as weighted set covering.  For each $t\subseteq U$, let binary decision variable $x_t$ indicate whether $t\in T$. The objective is to minimize $\sum_t |t|^2 x_t$, and the constraints are:
$$\sum_{t:r\subseteq t} x_t \ge 1$$ for all $r\in R$.

If the problem is too large to solve directly, you can use dynamic column generation to introduce promising $t$ sets on the fly as needed.

An alternative heuristic approach is to cluster the $r$ sets and assign one $t$ for each cluster.  If the resulting solution is good enough, you can stop. Otherwise, you can use these $t$ sets to initialize the column generation.

Comment: Hi Rob, that's great, thanks! The "dynamic column generation" approach is exactly what I need since the size of $\{t|t\subseteq U\}$ will be too large. Do you happen to have any good references? No worries if not, if that's the name used in the literature then I should be able to track some references down myself. Thanks

Comment: Chvatal, *Linear Programming* (1983)